# How can i merge two files by intermediate file with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I was trying to merge 3 tables, 2 of them contain information, and the another one is only the intermediate file,

the expected answer that i need is like this:

```
'userId', 'bookId', 'likes', 'title', 'author', 'Location', 'Age'
```

only i need to do a join like in database mysql, postgres and so on

these are the columns:

```
import pandas as pd

r_names = ['userId', 'bookId', 'likes']
cols1 = ['userId', 'bookId', 'likes']

u_names = ['userId', 'Location', 'Age']
cols2 = ['userId', 'Location', 'Age']

b_names = ['bookId','title', 'author']
cols3 = ['bookId','title', 'author']
```

i am reading the files like this:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('Ratings.csv', header=None, encoding="ISO-8859-1", names=r_names, usecols=cols1, index_col='userId')
df2 = pd.read_csv('Users.csv', header=None, encoding="ISO-8859-1", names=u_names, usecols=cols2, index_col='userId')
df3 = pd.read_csv('Books.csv', header=None, encoding="ISO-8859-1", names=b_names, usecols=cols3, index_col='bookId')
```

but i noticed that only its merging 2 files the information is not full

```
df4 = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='outer', on=['userId'])
df5 = pd.merge(df3, df4, how='outer', on=['bookId'])

df5.to_csv('dataset', sep='\t', encoding='utf-8')
result = df5.head(10)
print("First 10 rows of the DataFrame:")
print(result)
```

Comment: It's difficult to answer without a reproducible example, we do not have your files so you must provide DataFrame constructors instead, and the matching expected output

Comment: @mozway i am using this files https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/arashnic/book-recommendation-dataset/data?select=Books.csv only for the question i changed the column names

Comment: Can you still provide a minimal reproducible example? Large files are usually not good as example. Also you haven't showed the expected output.

Comment: @mozway there is not a way to join like a database?

Comment: Probably yes, but to be honest I've not even tried to think of the logic. I would with a clear reproducible example and the matching expected output.

Comment: but its needed the datas? as far as know the columns are very important, and the relatioship are many to many, thats why there is an intermediate table

Comment: the expected answer would be like this 'userId', 'bookId', 'likes', 'title', 'author', 'Location', 'Age', i put in my question

Comment: Sorry but without a clear [MRE](/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (see [here](/q/20109391/16343464) for pandas), the question cannot be answered and should be closed.

Comment: @mozway sorry i tried to create a MRE question, please can you see my question please

Comment: Thanks for your effort, and what is the exact expected output given those 3 inputs?

Comment: I think the issue may be arising because you're making userId your index in df1 and df2. In which case you need to merge the df1 and df2 using something more along the lines of `df4 = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='outer', left_on=df1.index, right_index=True)` or `df4 = df1.merge(df2, how='outer', left_index=True, right_index=True)`. I probably would avoid this whole thing and just not define those columns as indices and then your merges should work fine I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest importing your data a little differently (i.e not making the key columns your indices). There's nothing wrong with making your key columns your indices but your existing merges will work just fine if you import the data a little differently - totally up to you. So either change the import (as below) or change how you merge :)

My suggestion:

```
import pandas as pd

rating_names = ['userId', 'bookId', 'likes']
cols1 = ['userId', 'bookId', 'likes']
user_names = ['userId', 'Location', 'Age']
cols2 = ['userId', 'Location', 'Age']
books_names = ['bookId','title', 'author']
cols3 = ['bookId','title', 'author']

df1 = pd.read_csv('Ratings.csv', header=0, encoding="ISO-8859-1", names=rating_names, usecols=cols1)
df2 = pd.read_csv('Users.csv', header=0, encoding="ISO-8859-1", names=user_names, usecols=cols2)
df3 = pd.read_csv('Books.csv', header=0, encoding="ISO-8859-1", names=books_names, usecols=cols3)

df4 = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='outer', on=['userId'])
df5 = pd.merge(df3, df4, how='outer', on=['bookId'])
```

Top 10 rows of df5:

| bookId | title | author | userId | likes | Location | Age |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0195153448 | Classical Mythology | Mark P. O. Morford | 2.0 | 0.0 | stockton, california, usa | 18.0 |
| 0002005018 | Clara Callan | Richard Bruce Wright | 8.0 | 5.0 | timmins, ontario, canada | NaN |
| 0002005018 | Clara Callan | Richard Bruce Wright | 11400.0 | 0.0 | ottawa, ontario, canada | 49.0 |
| 0002005018 | Clara Callan | Richard Bruce Wright | 11676.0 | 8.0 | n/a, n/a, n/a | NaN |
| 0002005018 | Clara Callan | Richard Bruce Wright | 41385.0 | 0.0 | sudbury, ontario, canada | NaN |
| 0002005018 | Clara Callan | Richard Bruce Wright | 67544.0 | 8.0 | toronto, ontario, canada | 30.0 |
| 0002005018 | Clara Callan | Richard Bruce Wright | 85526.0 | 0.0 | victoria, british columbia, canada | 36.0 |
| 0002005018 | Clara Callan | Richard Bruce Wright | 96054.0 | 0.0 | ottawa, ontario, canada | 29.0 |
| 0002005018 | Clara Callan | Richard Bruce Wright | 116866.0 | 9.0 | ottawa, , | NaN |
| 0002005018 | Clara Callan | Richard Bruce Wright | 123629.0 | 9.0 | kingston, ontario, canada | NaN |

Comment: i think userid should appear many times because the relationship is many to many

Comment: The userid does appear many times. I just provided the first 10 rows to show that the output format is as you expected. I cannot post the entire 1324564 rows to this answer. I ran the following code: `df5['userId'] = df5['userId'].astype(str); user_id_counts = df5['userId'].value_counts()` to count the occurance of all userIds, and (for example) userid 11676 occurs 13602 times in df5